# MongoVue and Guid

Tags: c#, mongodb, guid

I would like to insert a Guid using the mongoVue tool, how can I do it ?

To explain the context, I used to copy the json of my collection (thanks to Text View tab) and paste it in my txt file instead of using mongodump. But when I create a new collection and paste it the json from previous copy, my guid binary type is now appeared as an ""object Id"", then the problem is: I can't map in my C# code the Object ID to my Guid field. 
Thats why I'd like to know if it's possible to insert a guid in MongoVue.

Thanks guys.
John

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the following notation to enter GUIDs in MongoVUE:

```
{
guid_field: new Guid("3bed978a-dc87-4fa4-8a1a-f0679387fa7e")
}
```

To insert a new Guid (Guid.NewGuid()), you may enter:

```
{
guid_field: new Guid()
}
```

All guids are converted to Binary type-3 values.

Comment: I right clicked and hit insert key and used type json and put in the format you showed in the textarea, but i got the error:  "Data Input Error - Please validate your value".  The details say:
Data Input Error - Please validate your value
JSON reader expected a type name but found 'Guid'.
Type: System.IO.FileFormatException

any ideas?

Comment: Note that as of MongoVUE 1.4.2 and newer, the syntax has changed: `Guid() is deprecated. Instead use “CSGUID(‘…’)” to parse .NET GUIDs.`
from [changelog](http://www.mongovue.com/downloads/)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure it can answer your question, but this post can help: http://www.mongovue.com/2010/09/13/using-objectids/

Comment: thanks for your answer. Their website talking about object id doesn't help much. I guess there're unfortunately no possibility to insert a document with a Guid

Answer (score 0):

When I insert an instance of the following class:

```
public class C {
    public Guid Id;
    public int X;
}
```

It looks like this in MongoVUE Text View:

```
/* 0 */
{
  "_id": {
    "$binary": "q4TTjt8k4UyaJI6FwuZ1EQ==",
    "$type": "03"
  },
  "X": 1
}
```

Where the GUID has been represented as BSON binary value of sub type 3, which is NOT an ObjectId.

To insert a GUID in MongoVUE you would have to create a BSON binary value of sub type 3. The hard part is figuring out the Base64 value to use.

In addition, there is an issue with the storage of UUIDs in general in MongoDB. The three drivers (C#, Java and Python) that currently support UUIDs have in the past used different byte orders for the binary representation of the UUID, which makes life really hard.

Future versions of the drivers will use a new binary sub type 4 for UUIDs and will all standardize on the official UUID network byte order (the 16 bytes are stored in the same order as they appear in the string representation of the UUID).

The current version of the C# driver (version 1.1 was just released) has some experimental support for dealing with different GUID representations (see the GuidRepresentation enum and where it is used).

Comment: I experimented some more with MongoVUE and I was able to reproduce the issue. When inserting a document where the _id has a binary sub type 3 value the _id gets replaced with an ObjectId by MongoVUE. I've emailed the author of MongoVUE to ask about that. If you have a choice, the path of least resistance would be to use ObjectId instead of Guid. We do however intend to fully suport Guids.